# CSS Firefox and IE9 not styling div and p classes, Chrome and Safari are

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have no doubt that this will end up being some rookie css error on my part, but I can't figure out why Chrome and Safari render this page the way I would like and expect, while Firefox and IE9 will not:

http://turtlemountainbrewing.com/wordpress/beers-on-tap/

For the text "Guest tap:" and "TMBC DRAFT LIST" I have a div at width 100% with the css set to align the text-center, with a bottom margin and border, but Firefox seems to ignore these rules entirely, which don't even show up in the css when I inspect the element. It also won't render some colored circle divs I have floating next to the beer titles.

This is also affecting the links I have in the right footer area in a similar fashion.

It seems something is canceling these style rules out but I can't figure exactly what.

Comment: Page checked: http://turtlemountainbrewing.com/wordpress/beers-on-tap/
Total errors found: 76 (Parsing: 13, HTML: 63)
Total warnings found: 1 (Parsing: 1)
(X)HTML used for this page: HTML 5.1


**start by validating your markups**

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML markup and CSS in your question (rather than just providing a link to your website).

Comment: ps. Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Answer (score 3):

In this [stylesheet](http://turtlemountainbrewing.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/lotus/css/other/custom.css?ver=28.6) you have a syntax error.

**You have:**

```
.beerheader {
   text-align: center; 
   width: 100%; 
   margin: 0 0 40px 0; 
   border-bottom:solid 1px #b3b59b; 
   !important
 }
```

**This it what it should be:**

```
.beerheader {
   text-align: center; 
   width: 100%; 
   margin: 0 0 40px 0; 
   border-bottom:solid 1px #b3b59b !important; 
 }
```

*I am not positive this is the problem. But it would be my first guess. Also on a side note I would suggest using header tags for headers instead of paragraph tags. And like others have mentioned, validating your code is also a good idea.*

Answer (score 1):

- Page checked:    http://turtlemountainbrewing.com/wordpress/beers-on-tap/
- Total errors found:  76 (Parsing: 13, HTML: 63)
- Total warnings found:    1 (Parsing: 1)
- (X)HTML used for this page:  HTML 5.1

When it 'bugs' in a browser or 2, and not in another browser or 2, i validate the html and MOST OF THE TIME, it fixes what some say beeing 'bugs' but what i say is broken markups.

About validating : http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/  and  http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

line 370 in css/other/custom.css remove double quote mark

line 442 in the same file !important should be before the ; mark

You can use a css validator in order to check these kind of errors ;)

for example http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator